# How to replace the product by product's form view using odoo js

Tags: javascript, odoo-10, odoo-11

How to **replace** the product by product's form view. When click on product it will open the product form view and fill all the fields using JS.

I used the following code. It  open the product's form view on click but not fill the fields.

```
selected_item: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // var name = e.currentTarget.dataset.action_name;
    // var oe_id = $(event.currentTarget).data('id');
    return this.do_action({
        type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
        res_model: 'product.product',                
        view_type: 'form',
        view_mode: 'form',
        views: [[false, 'form']],             
        target: 'current',
    });
}
```

Comment: Specify which record you need to show by adding: `res_id: res_id,`

Comment: You can specify id from py too.

Comment: Thank you @Zety and Keval. Now, its working.

Comment: Feel free to flag the comments as usefull.

Comment: @Zety you should convert your comments into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify which record you need to show by adding: `res_id: res_id,`.

To specify the record id you can try:

```
selected_item: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // var name = e.currentTarget.dataset.action_name;
    var oe_id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id'); 
    return this.do_action({
        type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
        res_model: 'product.product',                
        view_type: 'form',
        view_mode: 'form',
        res_id: oe_id,
        views: [[false, 'form']],             
        target: 'current',
    });
}
```